# How to put a figure on below paragraph in latex

Tags: floats

I want put figure below the paragraph in Latex (one page) i use winshell but always it's apply the figure above the paragraph

note: there is enough space to put figure I want to put figure below the paragraph in one page both figure and paragraph should be in one page but always figure go above how solve this

==================

I put caption here !

```
\begin{figure} 
\centering
\includegraphics[width=4in]{image}
\caption[my image]{Imy image}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: thanks I found it work with 
            \begin{figure}[!ht]

Comment: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/keeping-tables-figures-close-to-where-they-are-mentioned and the links within.

Answer (score 7):

Figures (environment `figure`) and tables (environment `table`) are floating objects. That means LaTeX tries to place them optimal in your document. The best place to print them is at the top of the page.

Use the parameter `[ht]` to advice LaTeX to place the figure either here (`h`) or at the top (`t`) of the (next) page: `\begin{figure}[ht]`.

With `!` you can instruct LaTeX to make the position of the graphic opposite typographical conventions. That is, the graphic will be placed preferred here. Do not use `!` if possible.

Comment: `!` doesn't (directly at least) affect the preference of one float area over another. If `h` is included it is used in preference to other float areas if placing a float there does not invalidate the constraints. `!` removes most of the numeric constraints on the number of floats that may appear in each area and the proportions of the page that they may take up.